# bootstrap 4 in symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I try add bootstrap4 in project symfony4 but bootstrap is not add in project

code twig.yaml:

```
twig:
paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
```

and I remove :

```
paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
debug: '%kernel.debug%'
strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
```

but also error bootstrap is not add .

code index.html.yml:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

    {% block title %}Hello {% endblock %}

    {% block body %}
    <div class="container">
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_widget(form, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} } )}}
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-success" />

    {{ form_end(form) }}
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

and this result .. so bootstrap4 is not add:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The Bootstrap 4 form theme from Symfony only adds Bootstrap *classes* to your form inputs, it **does not** load or include Bootstrap in any way; that is up to you.

Please refer to [[1]](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/introduction/) for documentation on how to include Bootstrap 4 into your templates.

Answer (score 1):

- keep your initial twig configuration :

  ```
  twig:
  paths: ['%kernel.project_dir%/templates']
  debug: '%kernel.debug%'
  strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
  form_themes: ['bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig']
  ```
- Make sure the SF4 bootstrap file is installed on your platform :

  [prjDir]/vendor/symfony/twig-bridge/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig
- check that *Bootstrap 4* assets (css, js) files are installed in your public directory, and correctly referenced by your `index.html.twig` via `base.html.twig` and not `'index.html.yml`'
- example of base.html.twig (extract ...)

  ```
  ...
  <!-- Icons -->
  {% block head_icons %}
  <link href="{{ asset('vendors/css/flag-icon.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{ asset('vendors/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{ asset('vendors/css/simple-line-icons.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="{{ asset('vendors/css/bootstrap-4-navbar.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  {% endblock %}

  <!-- Main styles for this application -->
  {% block main_styles %}
  <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
  {% endblock %}
  ...
  ```

Also check for JS includes in the file : `base.html.twig` 
Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

If someone still got this issue, the solution that I found is:

create a folder named `css` under `public` folder in your project, and put `bootstrap.min.css` file inside it.

then, in `base.html.twig` put `<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">` just before `{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}`

And that's it, Hope it helps :)